# Facebook Graph Api user_groups related error

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I wanted to use Graph Api to fetch the groups where user is member. But since 2.4, FB has deprecated the user_groups permission. In Graph Api Explorer, when I tried it with v2.3, it returns the results as expected. After seeing this, I implemented the same in my app with the version parameter of GraphRequest. Doing this, did not show me the results, instead they showed the error of permission.

What should I do then? Is there any way to use v2.3 for Graph Api? As per the sdk, my current Graph Api is 2.9

Answer (score 1):

Use `user_managed_groups` instead, there is no other way. You can only access groups you manage and you cannot go back to an older API version. Even with an older App it would be pointless, see deprecation info in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog